# Как передать данные на другую страницу asp.net mvc, из контроллера

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, controller

На главной странице пользователь вводит данные, производится их расчёт, результат нужно отобразить на другой странице.

Как я понял нужно использовать в конце расчёта переадресацию, но как "достать" данные из контроллера... прошу подскажите

мой код:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(int number_D, int number__d, int number_H, int number_Pripysk_d,
            int number_Dopysk_delta)
        {
            const decimal pi = 3.14M;
            const decimal Yd_ves = 0.0000000078M;

            // считаем припуск 
            decimal H_Zagotovki = Convert.ToDecimal(number_H + number_Pripysk_d);
            decimal D_Zagotovki = Convert.ToDecimal(number_D + number_Pripysk_d);
            decimal d_Zagotovki = Convert.ToDecimal(number__d - number_Pripysk_d);
```

// Дальнейшие расчёты

```
            decimal Massa_zagotovki_Obshaya_MAX = Massa_zagotovki_MAX - Massa_OTV_zagotovki_MAX;
            decimal Massa_zagotovki_Obshaya_MIN = Massa_zagotovki_MIN - Massa_OTV_zagotovki_MIN;

            return Redirect("~/Home/Rezult");

        }
```

Результаты нужно отобразить в табличке на новой странице

Comment: Как вариант, можно передать в GET параметры (URL search). Типа `?param1=value1&param2=value2`. Либо вернуть значения на фронтенд, а там уже выполнить нужный редирект с передачей данных. Либо научиться использовать AJAX запросы не изменяя страницу.

Comment: [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: Как вариант **Сессии**, или кэш по типу **memoryCache/Redis**